# addEventListener Two Functions

Tags: javascript, function, addeventlistener

How can I make it so that addEventListener() has two functions inside it?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Wrap your functions in a function.

```
const invokeMe = () => console.log('I live here outside the scope');
const alsoInvokeMe = () => console.log('I also live outside the scope'); 

element.addEventListener('event',() => {    
     invokeMe();
     alsoInvokeMe();    
});
```

Comment: Eight years and two months later, this is still helpful. I wonder why it was not working without the () at the back of the function names.

Answer (score 15):

Two major differences between the older model and the newer DOM Level 2 event
model is that 1) the newer model isn’t as dependent on a specific event handler property, and 2) you can register multiple event handler functions for any one event on any one object.(From: Learning JavaScript) For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myElement"> Please click here.</div>
        <script>
            function func0() {
                alert("Function0 is called");
            }
            function func1() {
                alert("Function1 is called");
            }
            document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", func0, true);
            document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", func1, true);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As, even you can remove a specific event handler function for one event on any one object. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="myElement"> Please click here.</div>
        <script>
            function func0() {
                alert("Function0 is called");
            }
            function func1() {
                alert("Function1 is called");
            }
            document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", func0, true);
            document.getElementById("myElement").addEventListener("click", func1, true);
            document.getElementById("myElement").removeEventListener("click", func0, true);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll give You a second approach:

```
document.querySelector('#ecxampleButton")
.addEventListener('click',console.log&console.warn)
```

This should be quite saf as EventListener is voided.
If You would You would like to use control flow in this case use &&, then the function after && will execute only if one before will return truable value .
Look at example :

```
         a=0;
        function stop(arg="argument"){
        console.log(arg,a)&&console.log(arg,a+=1)} // falsy(undefined) return breaks flow, as first function gives enough to execute conjunstion
        
        function add(arg){console.log(arg,a)&console.log(arg,a+=1)} 
    // increments variable 'a', as second function is executed
stop("stoper")
add("adder")
```

When You want to use function&function syntax then follow this example:    `document.querySelector('[role=combobox]').addEventListener('click',(e)=>console.log(e)&console.error(e))`

in case of function&&function  follow:

```
document.querySelector('[role=combobox]').addEventListner('click',console.log&&console.warn)
```

Answer (score -1):

Wrap your functions in a function. But need to send all params from  `addEventListener` callback (paramter `event`)

```
const callbackOne = (...props) => {
    console.log('callbackOne', ...props)
};
const callbackTwo = (...props) => {
    console.log('callbackTwo', ...props)
};

element.addEventListener('eventName',(...props) => {    
     callbackOne(...props);  
     callbackTwo(...props);
});
```

You