# multiple functions on add event listener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

**no jquery**

Hey! I'm trying to add multiple add Event Listener to a button.

```
 function logoContame(){
    var logo = document.getElementById("logoheader");
    logo.addEventListener("click", hideDivHistorias);
    logo.addEventListener("click", showDivPagina2);
 }



function showPagina2(){

var historias = document.getElementById("historias");

var hist1 = document.getElementById("hist1");
hist1.id="hist1";
hist1.style.opacity = "0.0";
historias.appendChild(hist1);

var hist2 = document.getElementById("hist2");
hist2.id="hist2";
hist2.style.opacity = "0.0";
historias.appendChild(hist2);

var hist3 = document.getElementById("hist3");
hist3.id="hist3";
hist3.style.opacity = "0.0";
historias.appendChild(hist3);

var textoabrigo= document.getElementById("textoabrigo");
textoabrigo.id="textoabrigo";
textoabrigo.style.opacity = "0.0";
historias.appendChild(textoabrigo);

showHeader();
startFadeInPagina2();
showDivPagina2();
menuPag1();
logoInicial();

}


//Criar Página Inicial 


function showDivPagina2(){

var div2 = document.getElementById('historias').style.visibility = 
"visible";

}
```

The first one works, but the second one doesn't. How can I fix this? I keep getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
at showPagina2 (code.js:290)
at HTMLButtonElement.logo1 (code.js:30)
```

and it is related to the "hist1" element.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by **doesn't work**? What error you are getting? Did you try to debug? Nobody understand here **doesn't work**.

Comment: @VicJordan Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'id' of null
    at showPagina2 (code.js:290)
    at HTMLButtonElement.logo1 (code.js:30)

Comment: post your HTML and JavaScript code as a running snippet. That will help to debug.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028853/addeventlistener-two-functions/25028877#25028877):

```
var logo = document.getElementById("logoheader");

logo.addEventListener('click',() => {    
     hideDivHistorias();
     showDivPagina2();    
});
```