# update multiple variables with onchange event in vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a series of functions that take in several inputs and generate several outputs.  When any input changes all the outputs should change as well.  The javascript is as follows:

```
function calcOne(a,b,c){
return a+b+c
}
function calcTwo(c,d){
return c*d
}
function calcThreee(d,e){
return d+e
}
var a = parseFloat(document.getElementByID('a').value);
var b = parseFloat(document.getElementByID('b').value);
var c = parseFloat(document.getElementByID('c').value);
var d = parseFloat(calcOne(a,b,c));
var e = parseFloat(calcTwo(c,d));
var f = parseFloat(calcThree(d,e));
document.getElementbyId("result_d").innerHTML = d;
document.getElementbyId("result_e").innerHTML = e;
document.getElementbyId("result_f").innerHTML = f;
```

So, when any of inputs a, b, or c change, then results in d, e, and f will change.

The corresponding html is:

```
<html>
<body>
<form id="myForm">
  <input id='a' value="1"><br>
  <input id='b' value="2"><br>
  <input id='c' value="3"><br>
</form>
<p id="result_d"></p>
<p id="result_e"></p>
<p id="result_f"></p>
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

How do I add an event listener such that any change to the form inputs a,b,c causes the displayed results d, e, and f to be updated? Note, that in my actual code (not the example above) there are about 50 variables and 50 functions, but all are very computationally lite (not much more than shown above) if that matters.

Comment: Great answer by @epascarello below. If you don't want to follow that route, you can always wrap functions in function as described here -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50742349/multiple-functions-on-add-event-listener

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap all your calculations in a function (`recalc` below) and call it once when the page loads, but also call it from an event listener for all the `input` elements

note also, that you don;t need to call `parseFloat` on the results of your functions - theyre already numeric.

```js
function calcOne(a,b,c){
return a+b+c
}
function calcTwo(c,d){
return c*d
}
function calcThree(d,e){
return d+e
}
document.querySelectorAll("input").forEach(x => x.addEventListener("change",recalc));

function recalc(){
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('a').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('b').value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('c').value);
  var d = calcOne(a,b,c);
  var e = calcTwo(c,d);
  var f = calcThree(d,e);
  document.getElementById("result_d").innerHTML = d;
  document.getElementById("result_e").innerHTML = e;
  document.getElementById("result_f").innerHTML = f;
}
recalc()
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id='a' value="1"><br>
  <input id='b' value="2"><br>
  <input id='c' value="3"><br>
</form>
<p id="result_d"></p>
<p id="result_e"></p>
<p id="result_f"></p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add an event listener to the form to detect the input was altered.

```js
var form = document.getElementById("myForm");

form.addEventListener("input", function (evt) {
    console.log("changed!", evt.target.id);
    // call a function that does the calculations
});
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <input id='a' value="1"><br>
  <input id='b' value="2"><br>
  <input id='c' value="3"><br>
</form>
```

Comment: This is good. It catches every key stroke.

Answer (score 0):

you can use an index since you have as many input as result para, with a input & result class:

```
let inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('input');
let results = document.getElementByClassName('result');

for(let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
    input[i].addEventListener('keydown', () => {
        result[i] = do_some_suff;
    });
}
```