# code trying to make object jump using requestanimationframe not working

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, requestanimationframe

Im trying to make an object jump using requestanimationframe. The finalposition variable hold the number of pixels the object should appear above the bottom of the page.

According to my code the object should smoothly move to the max height and then smoothly move down both events taking time=500ms ..But when I run the code the object immediately appears at the max height and then smoothly moves down in 500ms...How do i make both events happen smoothly over 500ms?

```
let time = {
  start: null,
  total: 500
};
const moveup = now => {
  if (!time.start) time.start = now;
  time.elapsed = now - time.start;
  let progress = time.elapsed / time.total;
  let position = progress * finalPosition;
  obj.style.bottom = position + 'px';
  if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(moveup);

};           

const movedown = now => {
  if (!time.start) time.start = now;
  time.elapsed = now - time.start;
  let progress = time.elapsed / time.total;
  let position = finalPosition*(1-progress);
  obj.style.bottom = position + 'px';
  if (progress < 1) requestAnimationFrame(movedown);

};       
function jump(){
    requestAnimationFrame(moveup);
    time.start=0;
    requestAnimationFrame(movedown);
} 
document.addEventListener('keydown',jump,false)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues here.

Unless your code is incomplete you've not got a finalPosition anywhere in your code.

More importantly the jump function is not properly waiting for the event, the entire function runs all at once, that is to say it does not wait for moveup before running movedown, instead they're running concurrently.

Presumably the reason you're observing only `movedown` is that both are happening on every frame, but `movedown` is happening after move up.

Ass you will be able to tell looking at the below snippet, what i've done here is to rearrange some of your existing code. I've moved the first `movedown` call to the end of the `moveup` loop, and reset time at the end of `movedown`.

```js
let finalPosition = 100;
let time = {
  start: null,
  total: 500,
};

let obj = document.querySelector('.foo');
const moveup = (now) => {
  if (!time.start) time.start = now;
  time.elapsed = now - time.start;
  let progress = time.elapsed / time.total;
  let position = progress * finalPosition;
  obj.style.bottom = position + 'px';
  if (progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(moveup);
  } else {
    time.start = 0;
    requestAnimationFrame(movedown);
  }
};

const movedown = (now) => {
  if (!time.start) time.start = now;
  time.elapsed = now - time.start;
  let progress = time.elapsed / time.total;
  let position = finalPosition*(1-progress);
  obj.style.bottom = position + 'px';
  if (progress < 1) {
    requestAnimationFrame(movedown);
  } else {
    time.start = 0;
  }
};       

function jump() {
  requestAnimationFrame(moveup);
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', jump, false);
```

```css
.foo {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

.frame {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  right: 50%;
  transform: translateX(50%) translateY(-50%);
  background-color: #cdb;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <div class="foo"></div>  
</div>
<button onclick="jump()">jump</button>
```

Comment: I do have a finalPosition..I didnt include it into the code snippet...But why does javascript execute the whole function at once ..shouldnt it first finish executing moveup and then movedown..for example in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028853/addeventlistener-two-functions both the statements will be logged onto the console and not only the second one right

Comment: @physics123 You're misunderstanding what requestAnimationFrame does. The code is executed in order. requestAnimationFrame, put simply, queues functions to run later. Your code puts both functions in the queue at the same time. Then when, later, requestAnimationFrame triggers the queued functions both of your functions are executed, and in the same order they were added. So you see only the result of the last function called.