# why does event Listener need two elements?

Tags: javascript, html

In the code below, you'll notice i have two event listeners

```
window.addEventListener("click", jump);
window.addEventListener("click", jump());
```

The problem is removing either one of these makes the event listener invalid i.e. it doesnt work, they have to both be present and I'm having a hard time figuring out why.

note: click to jump and view snippet in full page since i havent done the responsive part yet

```js
const ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
const obs = document.querySelector(".obstacle");
const score = document.querySelector("#s");



let temp = 0; // a temporary variable to stop event listener from running as soon as game starts

function jump() {
  let bottom = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

  if (temp > 0 && bottom === 150) {
    ball.style.bottom = "400px";

    setTimeout(() => {
      ball.style.bottom = "150px";
    }, 300);
  }
  temp++;
}

window.addEventListener("click", jump);
window.addEventListener("click", jump());

let z = 0; // intitial score to be incremented by each succesful second

setInterval(() => {
  let ballX = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

  let obsY = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obs).getPropertyValue('right'));

  if (ballX >= 150 && ballX <= 240 && obsY >= 785 && obsY <= 970) {
    ball.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    obs.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    ball.style.bottom = `${ballX}px`
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", jump);
    clearInterval();
  } else {
    s.innerHTML = z;
    z += 1;
  }
}, 10);

window.onload = () => {
  if (screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth) {
    alert("This game is best played in landscape, so rotate your phone if you can :)");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.screen {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;
  outline: solid 3px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: "Comic Neue";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.s {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px white;
}

#s-title {
  width: 40%;
}

#s {
  width: 60%;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
}

.obstacle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  bottom: 150px;
  background: red;
  animation: attack 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes attack {
  to {
    right: 1150px;
  }
}

.grass {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(55, 141, 52);
}

.ground {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background: rgb(82, 80, 69);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

  <title>Rollin</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='rollin.css'>
  <link rel='icon' href='assets/logo.ico'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="score">
      <div id="s-title" class="s">Score:</div>
      <div id="s" class="s">000000</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ball">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    .str0 {stroke:black;stroke-width:0.667;stroke-miterlimit:2.61313}
    .fil1 {fill:black}
    .fil2 {fill:#1A1A1A}
    .fil0 {fill:#AE0000}
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <g>
   <path class="fil0" d="M517.231 11.182c277.954,0 503.28,225.327 503.28,503.281 0,277.954 -225.326,503.281 -503.28,503.281 -277.954,0 -503.281,-225.327 -503.281,-503.281 0,-277.954 225.327,-503.281 503.281,-503.281z"/>
   <path id="1" class="fil1" d="M517.231 11.182c277.954,0 503.28,225.327 503.28,503.281 0,277.954 -225.326,503.281 -503.28,503.281 -277.954,0 -503.281,-225.327 -503.281,-503.281 0,-277.954 225.327,-503.281 503.281,-503.281zm338.197 165.084c-86.55,-86.551 -206.121,-140.084 -338.197,-140.084 -132.076,0 -251.648,53.533 -338.198,140.084 -86.55,86.55 -140.083,206.121 -140.083,338.197 0,132.076 53.533,251.647 140.083,338.197 86.551,86.551 206.122,140.084 338.198,140.084 132.076,0 251.647,-53.533 338.197,-140.084 86.551,-86.55 140.083,-206.121 140.083,-338.197 0,-132.076 -53.532,-251.647 -140.083,-338.197z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="fil2" d="M517.231 246.225c149.688,0 271.035,121.346 271.035,271.035 0,149.688 -121.347,271.035 -271.035,271.035 -149.689,0 -271.035,-121.347 -271.035,-271.035 0,-149.689 121.346,-271.035 271.035,-271.035zm184.58 86.454c-47.237,-47.237 -112.497,-76.454 -184.58,-76.454 -72.084,0 -137.343,29.217 -184.581,76.454 -47.237,47.238 -76.455,112.497 -76.455,184.581 0,72.083 29.218,137.343 76.455,184.58 47.238,47.237 112.497,76.455 184.581,76.455 72.083,0 137.343,-29.218 184.58,-76.455 47.237,-47.237 76.455,-112.497 76.455,-184.58 0,-72.084 -29.218,-137.343 -76.455,-184.581z"/>
  </g>
  <circle class="fil1 str0" cx="517.231" cy="517.26" r="100.656"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M213.398 645.876c-54.056,-27.029 -41.008,-69.901 -48.444,-92.065 -3.228,-9.623 -41.293,134.779 56.413,170.477 18.411,6.727 36.767,13.855 70.319,8.264 25.978,-4.33 61.512,-22.368 72.238,-53.613 12.934,-37.676 6.05,-56.363 -16.318,-82.46 -8.188,-9.553 -35.416,-37.28 -89.472,-20.504 -33.759,19.875 -36.584,43.161 -44.736,69.901z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M561.667 188.198c52.09,-14.249 81.039,-0.564 103.952,4.079 9.948,2.016 -96.076,-103.15 -175.843,-36.384 -15.032,12.581 -30.384,24.914 -42.317,56.766 -9.24,24.663 -11.386,64.455 10.311,89.367 26.161,30.039 45.787,33.421 79.571,27.098 12.367,-2.315 49.994,-12.031 62.493,-67.234 -0.333,-39.173 -19.087,-53.263 -38.167,-73.692z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M786.104 714.481c3.621,60.329 -40.031,70.465 -55.509,87.986 -6.72,7.607 137.369,-31.629 119.431,-134.093 -3.38,-19.308 -6.384,-38.769 -28.003,-65.031 -16.738,-20.332 -50.127,-42.086 -82.549,-35.753 -39.095,7.637 -51.837,22.942 -63.253,55.361 -4.179,11.868 -14.578,49.312 26.979,87.737 34.092,19.299 55.671,10.103 82.904,3.793z"/>
 </g>
</svg>


    </div>
    <div class="obstacle">
      <img src="assets/kakashi.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grass"></div>
    <div class="ground"></div>
  </div>

  <script src='rollin.js' defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The both event (click) listeners in `window` you wrote in the code runs ONE function, so removing one is same as removing all...

Comment: The second `addEventListener` doesn't do anything other than run the `jump` function, it doesn't return anything (let alone a function) to handle the events.

Comment: @phuzi i see, but removing the second one doesnt fix it either

Comment: @DhanaD. how can i fix it?

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask): _"**Describe the problem**. "It doesn't work" isn't descriptive enough to help people understand your problem. Instead, tell other readers what the expected behavior should be. Tell other readers what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it."_ + Add a [mcve], and this is not a minimal example...

Comment: You can use a different function name as written here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25028853/addeventlistener-two-functions

Comment: Have you tried replacing `window.addEventListener("click", jump());` by `jump();`? This has the same effect.

Comment: @SebastianSimon I dont quite understand?

Comment: You have `let temp = 0;` so the condition `temp > 0` clearly ignores the first click. Since you run `jump` once, you increment `temp` once so the next click is not ignored.

Comment: _“I dont quite understand?”_ — It’s the same thing phuzi already said in their first comment. `window.addEventListener("click", jump());` is the same thing as `jump();` in your case.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

How does this not work? You can try this better here: [JSFidlle](https://jsfiddle.net/Jesper02/z9m23rap/2/)

```js
const ball = document.querySelector(".ball");
const obs = document.querySelector(".obstacle");
const score = document.querySelector("#s");



let temp = 0; // a temporary variable to stop event listener from running as soon as game starts

function jump() {
  let bottom = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

  if (temp > 0 && bottom === 150) {
    ball.style.bottom = "400px";

    setTimeout(() => {
      ball.style.bottom = "150px";
    }, 300);
  }
  temp++;
}

window.addEventListener("click", jump);

let z = 0; // intitial score to be incremented by each succesful second

setInterval(() => {
  let ballX = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(ball).getPropertyValue('bottom'));

  let obsY = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(obs).getPropertyValue('right'));

  if (ballX >= 150 && ballX <= 240 && obsY >= 785 && obsY <= 970) {
    ball.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    obs.style.animationPlayState = "paused";
    ball.style.bottom = `${ballX}px`
    window.removeEventListener("keydown", jump);
    clearInterval();
  } else {
    s.innerHTML = z;
    z += 1;
  }
}, 10);

window.onload = () => {
  if (screen.availHeight > screen.availWidth) {
    alert("This game is best played in landscape, so rotate your phone if you can :)");
  }
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comic+Neue&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.screen {
  margin: 20px;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 500px;
  background: skyblue;
  outline: solid 3px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.score {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  font-size: 150%;
  font-family: "Comic Neue";
  font-weight: bold;
}

.s {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-shadow: 3px 3px 0px white;
}

#s-title {
  width: 40%;
}

#s {
  width: 60%;
}

.ball {
  position: absolute;
  left: 30px;
  bottom: 150px;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: red;
  transition: bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
  animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
  to {
    transform: rotate(720deg);
  }
}

.obstacle {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -150px;
  bottom: 150px;
  background: red;
  animation: attack 1.5s linear infinite;
  animation-play-state: running;
}

@keyframes attack {
  to {
    right: 1150px;
  }
}

.grass {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 125px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 25px;
  background: rgb(55, 141, 52);
}

.ground {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 125px;
  background: rgb(82, 80, 69);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset='utf-8'>
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>

  <title>Rollin</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='rollin.css'>
  <link rel='icon' href='assets/logo.ico'>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="screen">
    <div class="score">
      <div id="s-title" class="s">Score:</div>
      <div id="s" class="s">000000</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ball">
      <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="100%" height="100%" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
        viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <defs>
  <style type="text/css">
    .str0 {stroke:black;stroke-width:0.667;stroke-miterlimit:2.61313}
    .fil1 {fill:black}
    .fil2 {fill:#1A1A1A}
    .fil0 {fill:#AE0000}
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Layer_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <g>
   <path class="fil0" d="M517.231 11.182c277.954,0 503.28,225.327 503.28,503.281 0,277.954 -225.326,503.281 -503.28,503.281 -277.954,0 -503.281,-225.327 -503.281,-503.281 0,-277.954 225.327,-503.281 503.281,-503.281z"/>
   <path id="1" class="fil1" d="M517.231 11.182c277.954,0 503.28,225.327 503.28,503.281 0,277.954 -225.326,503.281 -503.28,503.281 -277.954,0 -503.281,-225.327 -503.281,-503.281 0,-277.954 225.327,-503.281 503.281,-503.281zm338.197 165.084c-86.55,-86.551 -206.121,-140.084 -338.197,-140.084 -132.076,0 -251.648,53.533 -338.198,140.084 -86.55,86.55 -140.083,206.121 -140.083,338.197 0,132.076 53.533,251.647 140.083,338.197 86.551,86.551 206.122,140.084 338.198,140.084 132.076,0 251.647,-53.533 338.197,-140.084 86.551,-86.55 140.083,-206.121 140.083,-338.197 0,-132.076 -53.532,-251.647 -140.083,-338.197z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
   <path class="fil2" d="M517.231 246.225c149.688,0 271.035,121.346 271.035,271.035 0,149.688 -121.347,271.035 -271.035,271.035 -149.689,0 -271.035,-121.347 -271.035,-271.035 0,-149.689 121.346,-271.035 271.035,-271.035zm184.58 86.454c-47.237,-47.237 -112.497,-76.454 -184.58,-76.454 -72.084,0 -137.343,29.217 -184.581,76.454 -47.237,47.238 -76.455,112.497 -76.455,184.581 0,72.083 29.218,137.343 76.455,184.58 47.238,47.237 112.497,76.455 184.581,76.455 72.083,0 137.343,-29.218 184.58,-76.455 47.237,-47.237 76.455,-112.497 76.455,-184.58 0,-72.084 -29.218,-137.343 -76.455,-184.581z"/>
  </g>
  <circle class="fil1 str0" cx="517.231" cy="517.26" r="100.656"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M213.398 645.876c-54.056,-27.029 -41.008,-69.901 -48.444,-92.065 -3.228,-9.623 -41.293,134.779 56.413,170.477 18.411,6.727 36.767,13.855 70.319,8.264 25.978,-4.33 61.512,-22.368 72.238,-53.613 12.934,-37.676 6.05,-56.363 -16.318,-82.46 -8.188,-9.553 -35.416,-37.28 -89.472,-20.504 -33.759,19.875 -36.584,43.161 -44.736,69.901z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M561.667 188.198c52.09,-14.249 81.039,-0.564 103.952,4.079 9.948,2.016 -96.076,-103.15 -175.843,-36.384 -15.032,12.581 -30.384,24.914 -42.317,56.766 -9.24,24.663 -11.386,64.455 10.311,89.367 26.161,30.039 45.787,33.421 79.571,27.098 12.367,-2.315 49.994,-12.031 62.493,-67.234 -0.333,-39.173 -19.087,-53.263 -38.167,-73.692z"/>
  <path class="fil1 str0" d="M786.104 714.481c3.621,60.329 -40.031,70.465 -55.509,87.986 -6.72,7.607 137.369,-31.629 119.431,-134.093 -3.38,-19.308 -6.384,-38.769 -28.003,-65.031 -16.738,-20.332 -50.127,-42.086 -82.549,-35.753 -39.095,7.637 -51.837,22.942 -63.253,55.361 -4.179,11.868 -14.578,49.312 26.979,87.737 34.092,19.299 55.671,10.103 82.904,3.793z"/>
 </g>
</svg>


    </div>
    <div class="obstacle">
      <img src="assets/kakashi.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="grass"></div>
    <div class="ground"></div>
  </div>

  <script src='rollin.js' defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: its not working on my side

Comment: It works, you just need to click the window once for it to start working. Calling jump() in any way fixes that problem.

Comment: I got it, so it was because of the temp value; thanks

Answer (score -1):

You can try to put the -listener- above the -jump- function and remove:

`-- window.addEventListener("click", jump()); --`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: How is the position of the `addEventListener` call going to make a difference?